# Office.js ContextMenu, what was clicked?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm doing a Word add-in using office.js, and have successfully registered a ContextMenu item and a callback function.

The function receives a [Office.AddinCommands.Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.addincommands.event) parameter, containing the source.id from my manifest.xml. No context of any sort.

I would expect a context menu to have access to the context, from which it was invoked.

Does anyone know how to get information about what was clicked?

**manifest.xml**

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="ContextMenu">
    <OfficeMenu id="ContextMenuText">
        <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1">
            <Label resid="ContextMenuItem.Label" />
            <Supertip>
                <Title resid="ContextMenuItem.Label"/>
                <Description resid="ContextMenuItem.Tooltip"/>
            </Supertip>
            <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
            </Icon>
            <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <FunctionName>doStuff</FunctionName>
            </Action>
        </Control>
    </OfficeMenu>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

**callback function**

```
function doStuff(event) {
   console.log("Got invoked!");
   console.log(event);
   event.completed();
}
```

Comment: This would only be a problem if more than one menu item calls the same function, right? If Button1Id1 is the only button that ever calls doStuff, then doStuff knows what was clicked.

Comment: Being a context menu, I would expect to have access to the context on which it was invoked.
Such as: Where in the document the right-click was performed, or on which piece of text in the document the right-click was performed, enabling me to provide something meaningful in relation to to the context.

Comment: I see. I thought you meant, what menu item was clicked. Try using `Document.getSelection()` to get the Range that was right-clicked. From there you can use the properties of the Range object that is returned to orient your code.

Comment: I guess that could work. There may not be anything selected, but in my case there would always be a content control, which i can get by loading 'parentContentControl'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no context object that provides information about where the document was right-clicked. You can use the `Document.getSelection()` to get the Range that was right-clicked. From there you can use the properties of the Range object that is returned to orient your code.